# How to find files containing a string N times or more often using egrep

Tags: bash, awk, terminal

I have a folder with about 400-500 SQL-files and need the names of
only those who contain the string `CREATE TABLE` 3 times or more often.

While the command
`$ egrep -rl "(CREATE TABLE)" ./*.sql`
prints me of course all file-names, the command
`$ egrep -rl "(CREATE TABLE.*){3}" ./*.sql`
does not print any at all ...

**Flags:**

- **`-R`** – recursive
- **`-L`** – files-with-matches | print only names of FILEs containing matches

Comment: ````CREATE TABLE```` 3 times within a file or 3 times for all the 400-500 sql files?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command

```
egrep -rl "(CREATE TABLE.*){3}" ./*.sql
```

looks for 3 `CREATE TABLE`'s on one line.
When they are on different lines, you need to do something different,
and when you have GNU grep, you are lucky: It has the option `-z`.

```
# minimal change of your command
egrep -zrl "(CREATE TABLE.*){3}" ./*.sql
# moving option E to the options as suggested by @anubhava
grep -zErl "(CREATE TABLE.*){3}" ./*.sql
```

Comment: ++ Good `grep` command but `-z` is only supported in `GNU grep` so better to use: `grep -zErl "(CREATE TABLE.*){3}" ./*.sql` since `egrep` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` will do the job:

```
awk 'FNR==1{n=0} /CREATE TABLE/{++n} n>2{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.sql
```

Comment: sir, IMHO wouldn't `exit` will comeout of `awk` command itself? I used `nextfile` to jump to next file.

Comment: This only prints me the name of the first matching file.

Comment: @PatrickSteiner, yes please I think `exit` will come out of command like I mentioned above too, could you please try my command once?

Comment: Ah that's true it should be `nextfile` instead of `exit`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 with `nextfile` instead of `exit` it worked for me, thank you!

Comment: @anubhava, first time I have beaten you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108682/5866580 :P

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Trying to beat both of you with a simple `grep` https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113222/3220113 ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this might fail if there are multiple "CREATE TABLE" strings on a single line. While I realize this might be tough in an SQL file, SQL unrelated it might fail.

Comment: @kvantour: Very valid point of variable not getting reset properly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. I am taking care of number of opened files in backend too here.

```
awk 'prev!=FILENAME{n=""}/CREATE TABLE/{++n} n>2{print FILENAME;prev=FILENAME;nextfile}' *.sql
```

Comment: ++ for using `nextfile` but global variable `n` needs to be reset to `0` as well and `close` is not needed

Comment: Be aware that this might fail if there are multiple "CREATE TABLE" strings on a single line. While I realize this might be tough in an SQL file, SQL unrelated it might fail.

Comment: @kvantour, updated my solution now, please check it and let me know?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the possibility of having multiple strings per line, (only covered by the answer of [Walter A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113222/8344060)), here is it's awk version (one that supports `nextfile`)

```
awk '(FNR==1){n=0}
     {n+=split($0,a,/CREATE TABLE/)-1}
     (n>2) {print FILENAME; nextfile}' */.sql
```

If you don't have GNU grep (according to Walter A's solution) and neither you have an awk with `nextfile`, the following solutions can be used (POSIX):

```
awk '(FNR==1){n=0; p=1}
     p {n+=split($0,a,/CREATE TABLE/)-1}
     (n>2) && p {print FILENAME; p=0}' */.sql
```

The difference between the two solutions are:

- Solution 1 will not process the full file as it will create an early termination per file if the condition is met.
- Solution 2 cannot do such an action, however we can reduce computational time by avoiding `split` if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: ++ good awk command to address multiple `CREATE TABLE` per line

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution

```
perl -le ' BEGIN { for(glob("*.sql")) { $x=qx(cat $_); $r++ for($x=~m/CREATE TABLE/g); print $_ if $r > 2 ; $r=0 } } '
```