# Search in VS Code for occurrences of term greater than N

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, vscode-extensions

Here's an example:

- My search term is `myTermABC`
- I have 100 files in my project
- 10 files contain `myTermABC`
- Only two of those files contain `myTermABC` more than once (the other 8 contain it only once)
- I only want VS Code to return the two files that contain `myTermABC` more than once.

How to do this?

Is this even possible?

Maybe there's an extension that enables this functionality?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/54113222/1971662, it seems this is possible directly in the CLI (e.g. `grep -zErl "(myTermABC.*){2,}" ./**/*.txt`). For some reason that same REGEX doesn't work in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

In vscode search across files you have to specifically tell it to include newlines.  The `dot` doesn't do this in a search in vscode.

So this find should work: `(myTermABC[.\n]*){2,}`

Comment: From my testing I'm seeing that this does not work.

Comment: I tested it.  It works.